# Displaying JSON string in DIV

Tags: jquery, json

I have a problem with displaying JSON string in my DIV:

```
function populate(content) {
$.ajax({
    data: content,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('.output').append('<div class="article"><img src=' + item.image + '/><div>' + item.text + '</div></div>');
            });
    }
});
}
```

Can anybody help with my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/rtreosad/

Comment: You are getting a 414 Request-URI Too Large error

Comment: Oh ok. Can the problem get sorted?

Comment: That's just because the `$.ajax` function doesn't have an URL

Comment: Thank you @adaneo but how can I sort this issue?

Comment: Well, adding an url comes to mind ?

Comment: The problem is this JSON is getting from localStorage

Comment: Then why are you showing us an ajax function ?

Comment: sorry I am really numb got no idea how to work out any other way. Just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

As @adeneo mentioned my $.AJAX didn't have URL so I have done a further research and came up with this solution:

```
function populate(data) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function () {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $('.output').append('<div class="article"><div>' + item.text + '</div><div style="width:200px;height:100px;background-image: url(' + item.image + ')"></div></div>');
            });
    }
});
}
```

Please feel free to use if any one has got the same problem in future.

Comment: Please read jQuery $.ajax documentation. If you just want to loop through 'data', then you don't need to call an AJAX function, do you?